# It is possible to directly apply the modifier of the specified object?

Tags: python, scripting

So, I have some arbitrary object referred by the variable `target_object`. I can directly add the modifier to this object:

```
mod = target_obj.modifiers.new(type='BOOLEAN', name='Boolean')
mod.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
mod.object = tool_obj #some tool object
```

I have the one main question: is it possible to somehow directly apply this newly created modifier? I doesn't find any ways to do this, avoiding to use `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply()` which works with the active object only.

I have the secondary question: does some built-in function or method exist to get unique modifier's name? For unclear reasons the `name` parameter of the `new()` method is required and I do not wish to write the additional code to generate such name manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier = mod.name)
```

using the active object; as you indicated.  But I don't understand your concern with the name.  Modifiers are created with names, because `new` requires a name, so you don't have to modify the name for this to work.

As pointed out in the comments, you can use the *default* name in the new operator by typing `name=""` and Blender will sort out making a unique name.

Comment: Also you might want to use an override if `target_obj` is not the active object otherwise the operator won't work and throw `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply.poll() failed, context is incorrect`. eg : `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply({"active_object": target_obj}, modifier=mod.name)`

Comment: @Gorgious Good point, I'll clarify.

Comment: Of course I can set my object as active and apply the modifier via the `bpy.ops...` But I read that using the `bpy.ops` works slowly and it's recomended to avoid using it. Also my logic tells me if I can directly create the modifier then must be the way to directly apply it without refering to the entire Blender envirement and changing the context.

Comment: About the modifier's default name... As I wrote above the `new()` method requires the immediate name to put. If I miss this parameter the error occures (in opposing to `bpy.ops.object.modifier_add()`). So, I somehow need to "guess" whats name I must put to avoid the names conflict...

Comment: @LShadow77 `bpy.ops` is only slow if there are alternative methods.  Also, sometimes it doesn't matter if it's slow. You don't need to worry about the name conflict because you can use the default name, and Blender will generate a unique name by appending .NNN if it has to.

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, `name=""` works! I've not guessed to write this. Oh Blender, you turn my logic off!))

Comment: Yeah maybe we should stop systematically saying operators are bad to use in scripts. They are bad if you use them hundreds of times in loops but the difference won't even be measurable if you run them once or twice compared to their low-level counterparts. But they do have the problem to absolutely need a correct context to be run (active object, selected objects, 3d viewport, etc.)

Comment: @Gorgious OK, about my secondery question the problem is solved. But regarding to my main question... If I understand right, no another ways to applay modifier exists except making the object active and using `bpy.ops'. Right?

Comment: You can use an operator if the object isn't selected but you have to use an override dictionary with `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply({"active_object": target_obj}, modifier=mod.name)` You can learn more about operator overrides here : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context

Comment: @Gorgious thank You! It works, this is what I need!